# We used to have great water pressure everywhere, that 1 day it all came to an end. I replaced the bladder tank ,the t-pipe & everything that goes on

Tags: water-pressure

I replaced everything that I was told should be replaced after 20 years of great water pressure.  After replacing the bladder tank & accessories,i adjusted the pressure to 38, my relay is a 40/60, so I was told 2psi less than the cut on pressure.  Now I have water, but no where near the psi I had before! If someone flushes a toilet while someone's in she shower, u lose most of the pressure in the shower, down to a trickle. Homedepot told me I should lower the psi that is recommended, on a 40/60- instead 38, take it to 32-35 psi. Can anybody give me any suggestions?? Or is my well pump about to take a SH_T? Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks ppl,